# Only allow one NSWindow to be selectable until action is completed (Cocoa)

Tags: cocoa, events, nswindow, interaction

I have a program with many windows open. I want all windows to be visible, but only one window can be interactable, until a certain event has occured. e.g. pressing a button.

At the moment, I can still click another window, and interact with it, how do I only allow interaction with ONE window, until a certain event occurs?

Imagine this as the program:
[image]

I want only the frontmost Window to be selectable, if I try to select any of the other windows behind it, it should not work.

Does anoybody know how to do this?

Thanks!

Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want a [modal window](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/UsingModalWindows.html).